# rendering data in views based on the url

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url-routing

When the user is in the /home/ directory I want to render some particular view content but when the user typed in /home/users/someUser I want to check if the request is not a /home/ request and output some other content

so far I got that much

```
 if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && Request ???)
                {
                    <li>
                 <a class="btnAddTopTenFav icons">+</a> 
            </li> 
                }   else
                {
                    <li></li>
                }
```

I check if the user is logged in and then I need to check if he's at the home page or some other page.. how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check which controller you're coming from by writing `ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString()`

Comment: i guess i'd be interested in the controllers action because so far I only use one controller

Comment: Then you want `"action"`.  Also, you may want to use multiple controllers.